# quaternion.inverse() * quaternion is not zero

Tags: rotation, geometry, eigen, quaternions, eigen3

I'm using the Eigen C++ library. Multiplying a quaternion with it's inverse should always give the zero rotation, right?

I have a specific testcase where it doesn't.

```
// This case works fine:
OrientationTestsEigen(1.7118, 0.8036, 1.5977);
// This fails:
OrientationTestsEigen(1.7118679426016505, 0.80361404966200567, 1.5977764119637190);
```

Test code:

```
bool approxEqual(double a, double b)
{
    return fabs(a - b) < 0.0001;
}

void QuaternionToYPR(const Quaterniond& quat, double &y, double &p, double &r)
{
    Eigen::Vector3d rpy = quat.toRotationMatrix().eulerAngles(2, 0, 1);
    r = rpy.x();
    p = rpy.y();
    y = rpy.z();
}

void OrientationTestsEigen(double yaw, double pitch, double roll)
{
    // Convert Yaw, Pitch, Roll to Quaternion
    Eigen::AngleAxisd yawAngle(yaw, Eigen::Vector3d::UnitY());
    Eigen::AngleAxisd pitchAngle(pitch, Eigen::Vector3d::UnitX());
    Eigen::AngleAxisd rollAngle(roll, Eigen::Vector3d::UnitZ());
    Quaterniond quaternionRepresentation = rollAngle *  pitchAngle * yawAngle;

    // quat * quat.inverse() should result in zero rotation
    Quaterniond shouldBeZero = quaternionRepresentation * quaternionRepresentation.inverse();
    double y3, p3, r3;
    QuaternionToYPR(shouldBeZero, y3, p3, r3);
    assert(fabs(y3) < 0.001);
    assert(fabs(p3) < 0.001);
    assert(fabs(r3) < 0.001);
}
```

I find it very strange that the first case works, but the second (with only a tiny difference in values) fails. What I'm getting is:

- Testcase 1: yaw, pitch and roll are zero, as expected.
- Testcase 2: I'm getting -PI for yaw, PI for pitch, PI for roll. Pitch only goes up to 90°, so effectively this is yaw=0, pitch=0 and roll=180°.

Why do we get 180° roll in the second case, and not zero?

Comment: Can you show what the values of `shouldBeZero` are? Without checking myself, it should be the Identity matrix, no? If that's the case, then the code in `QuaternionToYPR` doesn't deal with all the cases well.

Comment: Expanding on my previous comment: `quat.toRotationMatrix()` should return the identity matrix, thus `eulerAngles` doesn't deal with the cases correctly (which often happens as there are degeneracies that aren't always kept in mind). Can you show the `eulerAngles` code?

Comment: Thanks, the problem was in the rotation matrix. It had some elements that were very small, but not zero. By detecting and setting those elements to zero, I'm now getting the expected results.
Apparently the eulerAngles function has some numerical problems with matrix elements that are almost zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same rotation can be represented by MULtiple Euler angles (yaw, pitch, roll).  So your comparison is not correct.

You can compare rotation matrices or estimate angle of rotation between result quaternion and Identity quaternion.

shouldBeZero.angularDistance(Quaterniond::Identity());